# Convert Smarty to normal PHP

Tags: php, smarty

I'm working on a old project and I don't want to use Smarty anymore so i need to convert some code back to normal again. I tried a couple of times with no luck so if someone could help me i would be very happy.

Here is the Smarty template file: http://tny.cz/ca234392

Here is the file mixed with smarty: http://tny.cz/d4256f07

The project is using the `mysql_` library but I don't want to use that any more, I will replace it with PDO ;)

Comment: Hi there. Just so you know, questions asked here generally should be of interest to a wide audience, and ideally show some prior effort. As it stands, I don't think this makes a good fit for the site. Since you have given this problem a try before, perhaps a good approach would be to show the original and your attempt, and where exactly you are getting stuck (ideally in the question rather than at shortened URLs). If this closes, then make those changes and it should reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smarty code should be easy to understand.

You should be able to replace the smarty part from the template with plain and simple PHP like this:

```
{if $error ne ""}
<div class="short_error">{$error}</div>
{/if}
```

becomes

```
<?php if($error != "") { ?>
<div class="short_error"><?php echo $error?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Once done simply include the new template file in the place of the smarty call.

Comment: What about this 

$template = new Smarty;
$template->assign('promo_methods', $availablePromotionalMethods);

all these assign how do i use it?

Comment: Learn programming. We're not here to do your homework.